# Why the messy use of a bulleted list in the bounty page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center

I just saw the [bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and it seems that someone decided to use a bulleted list for these statements:

> [image: Extract from bounty page]

I believe that those list items should be changed to a more homogenous format.

This is how it looks in my screen:

> [image]

(is a 1024x768 image)

Now, I expect it to looks like this:

> [image]

As you can see, the bullets start using slight to the right margin opposed to normal test (p tags) starts, and the text is aligned a bit more to the right.

This happens due the lack of `<ul>` tags englobing the `<li>` tags, hence it takes the `<div>` tag as point of reference for the margins. If you are saying "But Chrome/ium looks good", Chromium is broken. Firefox is displaying the broken source code, Chromium just tries to "fix" them.

I'm expecting it to look like the [What is reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) page. And if it's possible add some kind of title like "Caracteristics:" or "so, the bounty is:" or "what happens when I set a bounty:", dunno here.

Comment: For other readers: Look at the [What is reputation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) help article and its lists, and then look at the [What is a bounty?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) help article and its lists. The bulleted list styling is a little messed up. @Braiam, maybe instead of requesting this be turned into paragraphs, you could just request the CSS be fixed and tag this question with [[tag:bug]] [[tag:css]] [[tag:help-center]]?

Comment: Nice example, yeah, I'm expecting it to looks like the What is reputation? page. And if it's possible add some kind of title.

Comment: I would upvote this if it were a request to fix the buggy CSS, but as a request to change these so they're no longer a list at all... well, this question is already downvoted enough I don't need to downvote it further. :)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I was under the assumption that it was a intended paragraph.

Comment: Doesn't display like that in Chromium 30. Bullets are aligned with the left text margin.

Comment: @Mat Chromium is broken. But you might like to see the source code, it starts using `<li>` tags immediately instead using `<ol>` or `<ul>` as said in [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li). Firefox is displaying the broken source code, chromium just try to "fix" them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a `<ul>`, but it was missing a `</ul>`, which caused the formatting to be a little off. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

They used bullets, but they did not use a list of bullets.

They have:

```
<p>
<li>Shark fin soup</li>
<li>Palm oil</li>
<li>Blood diamonds</li>
</p>
```

But should be using:

```
<ul>
<li>Canvas bags</li>
<li>Public transport</li>
<li>Libraries</li>
</ul>
```

The lack of indent you expect from normal lists comes from this minor detail.

Comment: ARGGGGKDJKD! You just got the problem 12 secs before :S